# Malfunctioning Nesting on Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm developing a basic project on Rails 4.0 using Bootstrap version 3.

I'm trying to set up two nested divs under a main div but there's something wrong, the child divs aren't respecting the size of the parent div. (i.e., are *overflowing* from the parent div)

I've written the demo html in here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/g3p8K/2) (it's got a few ruby markers but it just be well understood even by those who have no ruby experience.)

Things I have already tried:

- using `col-xs-*` instead of `col-md-*`
- using another bootstrap version (from maxcdn which is the official provider)

[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/g3p8K/2)

This is what it looks like on my browser:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you should be nesting the `well` inside the `col-md-*`.

The `row` has the negative margin, then the `col-md-*` uses `padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px` to negate that.  The `well` is overriding those padding rules.

```
<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="well">
    <h3>Descrição:</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g3p8K/3/

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the `.row` class have the styles

```
margin-right: -15px;
margin-left: -15px;
```

either you can remove the dom or add a app.css to overwrite these styles

Comment: Then nesting doesn't work? It isn't mentioned here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Comment: sorry i miss understood your question，the answer @davidpauljunior provide is correct.